# Win32 API P-Invoke to bring a disk online, offline, and set unique ID

Tags: c#, pinvoke, disk, hard-drive

I am currently using Diskpart to accomplish these functions, but i would like to be able to use P-Invoke and not have to shell out to an external process in my C# app.

The example Diskpart scripts are:

```
//Online a disk
Select disk 7
disk online

// Reset GPT Identifier
select disk 7
UNIQUEID DISK ID=baf784e7-6bbd-4cfb-aaac-e86c96e166ee
```

I tried searching pinvoke.net but could only find functions that dealt with volumes, not disks. Any idea on how to accomplish these diskpart commands using Pinvoke?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what Dispart does but I'd suggest looking at WMI which might have this kind of functionality. It's usually a good place to look when you need to do something less common in Windows.

There's the `Storage WMI Classes` which might have something useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567016%28VS.85%29.aspx

Edit: removed the suggestions about Volumes since I had missed that you're not interested in that.

Comment: I did find win32_diskdrive but it doesn't have any useful methods for what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [DeviceIOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(VS.85).aspx) API?

If not, I would look into using WMI. In particular, take a look at the WMI [WIN32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx) or [WIN32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(VS.85).aspx) classes.

Comment: It looks like CreateFile and DeviceOControl may be where I need to start. Any examples would be great. I'm no Win32 programmer :)

Comment: I can write something up, but it's going to take some time. You can examples of using the API at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.deviceiocontrol. This article may also be of use: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx